# How to write a gridview like asp .net in Java MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

How to write a gridview like asp .net in Java MVC ?

Like edit function, once press edit link, the field become textbox for input

Comment: MVC is a pattern, not a GUI framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at GWT, SmartGWT. Those are GUI toolkit and would help you out. Also you can try JQuery